# How-to use predicates for customer where LINQ query in Entity Framework, Extension Method "Search by Words"

Tags: linq, search, where-clause, predicate

I would like to build a custom linq query using predicates.

Instead of using a static `Where` clause, i.e. ...

```
public IEnumerable<Entities.BusinessDirectory.BDEntity> Search(string searchExpression)
{
    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    return db.BDEntities
             .Where(x => searchExpression.Split(' ').Any(y => x.Value.Contains(y)));
}
```

... I am extending the DbContext with the generic method `Search(predicate, searchExpression)`, which shall have the same effect as the static method (see above)

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(
        this DbSet<T> dbSet, 
        Expression<Func<T, object>> predicate, 
        string searchExpression)
      where T : class, new()
    {
        //Experimental
        return dbSet
            .Where(x => searchExpression.Split(' ').Any(y => predicate.Contains(x)));
    }
}
```

However, I receive the following error:

> Error 6   Instance argument: cannot convert from
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' to
>   'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'    Extensions.cs

Comment: What does `predicate` stands for ?  Please add an example, of how this method is used.

Comment: You are not disposing the database context `db`. But you are surely doing it in your real application, right? Are you?

Answer (score 8):

The simple answer is that you may just add a predicate to a query `Where` clause, bear in mind that the definition of a `Where` predicate is that it returns `bool`. Ultimately your expression must be a `boolean` expression in order to be added into a `Where` clause.

```
Expression<Func<BDEntity, bool>> predicate = (BDEntity entity) => entity.Field == "TEST";
var query = context.BDEntities;

if (predicate != null)
    query = query.Where(predicate);

// expand to get the results.
var results = query.ToList();
```

### dynamic expression

If you need to build up an expression like `_ => _.MyFieldValue == "TEST"` at runtime, that's a little more tricky.

Given a predicate `_ => _.DatabaseField` and a string value `"TEST"`, create an expression suitable for 
entity framework to create a `where` clause that tests the predicate.

This method will build an appropriate `Equal` expression.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildEqualPredicate<T>(
    Expression<Func<T, string>> memberAccessor,
    string term)
{
    var toString = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(term), typeof(string));
    Expression expression = Expression.Equal(memberAccessor.Body, toString);
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        expression,
        memberAccessor.Parameters);
    return predicate;
}
```

The following assertions will pass:

```
var expression = Predicate.BuildEqualPredicate<MyDbEntity>(_ => _.DatabaseField, "TEST");
expression.Compile()
    .Invoke(new MyDbEntity { DatabaseField = "TEST" })
    .Should().BeTrue();
expression.Compile()
    .Invoke(new MyDbEntity { DatabaseField = "ANOTHERVALUE"})
    .Should().BeFalse();
```

The predicate can be used by entity framework by including the predicate in a where clause.

```
var predicate = PredicateExtensions.BuildEqualPredicate<MyDbEntity>(
    _ => _.DatabaseField,
    "TEST");
var results = context.DbEntity.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

### additionally

You can do a little more with the member expression, like using `StartsWith` and `Contains` to create more complex predicates.

```
Expression<Func<T, string>> memberAccessor = _ => _.DBEntityField;
```

You can dynamically create a predicate like this, in this example it creates a predicate that checks whether or not a string `StartsWith` a particular value, `or is null`.

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildPredicate(
    string term,
    Expression<Func<T, string>> memberAccessor)
{
    var startsWith = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var isNull = typeof(string).GetMethod("IsNullOrEmpty", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var toString = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(term), typeof(string));
    Expression expression = Expression.Call(
        memberAccessor.Body,
        startsWith,
        new Expression[] { toString });
    expression = Expression.Or(expression, Expression.Call(
        isNull,
        toString));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        expression,
        memberAccessor.Parameters);
    return predicate;
}
```

This will give you an expression that evaluates to this:

```
Expression<Func<BDEntity, bool>> expression = _ => 
   string.IsNullOrEmpty(term)
   || _.DBEntityField.StartsWith(term)
```

This expression has several advantages:

- it can be converted into suitable `SQL`
- all records are returned when `term` is `null` or `empty`
- `StartsWith` ensures that an appropriate index *can* be used.

The `expression` may be similarly added to the query with `query = query.Where(expression)`, replacing `StartsWith` with `Contains` will search for any occurrences within the string, but you will **forgo any SQL index optimizations**, so it's contraindicated.

Comment: Hello @Jim, I think you're pointing me into the right direction. However I can still not establish an extension method of the inherited DbContext class by using a predicate ('Expression<Func<T, object>> predicate') defining a Property == searchExpression.
How can I build an Expression<Func<T, bool>> by combining a predicate and a string?

Comment: I am updating the answer now.

Comment: Great answer. I would also add that you need to be careful with captures in Linq Expressions. For example `searchExpression.Split(' ')` would capture `seachExpression` and then call `string.Split`, which isn't EF callable.

Comment: Jim - taking your example: it it possible to use T instead of class BDEntity, i.e. `Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = (T entity) => {field} == searchExpression;`  whereas {field} is the predicate Expression<Func<T, object>> in the function parameter?

Comment: You may use any placeholder for {T}. The generic type needs to be resolved to a particular class or interface for it to have a particular property. Given: `(T entity) => entity.SomeField == searchExpression`, T needs to be an interface or class that has a property called `SomeField`. What I typically do in such a case is make sure that each entity framework entity with the property `SomeField` inherits a particular interface. `ISearchable` for instance. All `ISearchable` entities will then have the property `SomeField`. Then type {T} `where T : ISearchable`

Comment: @Herdy, did you come right - is the answer acceptable?